# The database cannot be opened because of it's version. Connecting .mdf file to Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sql-server, ssms, visual-studio-2019

I have Visual Studio 2019 and MS SQL Server Management Studio 18 and SQL Server 2019 installed localdb.
Everything updated.

I have created in Visual Studio new local database file .mdf it is listed on my solution explorer.
I wanted to work on it, creating tables etc by using MS SQL Server Management. So I attach created .mdf file to my localdb databases. Create tables, save. All works fine. In Visual Studio I double click on .mdf file in solution explorer so it would normally add to my data connections also but it can't be done here is the error:

> The database 'D:\VSREPOS\REPOS\CARNOTE\CARNOTE\DATABASE.MDF' cannot be
> opened because it is version 904. This server supports version 852 and
> earlier. A downgrade path is not supported. Could not open new
> database 'D:\VSREPOS\REPOS\CARNOTE\CARNOTE\DATABASE.MDF'. CREATE
> DATABASE is aborted. An attempt to attach an auto-named database for
> file D:\VSrepos\repos\CarNote\CarNote\Database.mdf failed. A database
> with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it
> is located on UNC share.

So I tried other way around.
I created new database in MS SQL Server Management with version 852 I found that it is SQL Server 2016 (options-> compatibility level - 2016). I stopped my localdb server in configuration manager to copy .mdf file and .ldf file to my Visual Studio project repo. I have added that database file to Visual Studio solution explorer. So again I try to add that database to server explorer by double clicking it also tried to add it by adding new connection. I receive exactly same error as above.

I totally don't understand what is the problem. Well ok it's about the version but I only have one local sql server so how come visual studio would use different version. How to solve this? Any idea?

There is one more thing. I was working on a project that was connected to online sql server. Now I need to make it offline. I need to have it connected to .mdf file. It's a small project. I did not had any sql server locally before so I installed sql server express 2019 today so I could attach visual studio .mdf file and work on it there. What I'm missing? Does Visual Studio have it's own sql server and it's own version? How to update it to my local version as it says that Visual Studio have outdated 852 version and .mdf file has version 904. This does not make sense to me because I tried to make it also other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution here:

https://medium.com/cloudnimble/upgrade-visual-studio-2019s-localdb-to-sql-2019-da9da71c8ed6

Installing my local sql server did not updated the code itself.

I have opened a Powershell window and ran the following commands:

> ```
> sqllocaldb stop projectsv13
> sqllocaldb delete projectsv13
> sqllocaldb stop mssqllocaldb
> sqllocaldb delete mssqllocaldb
> sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB
> ```

Actually it did not found any projectsv13 but it re-created mssqllocaldb.
Now my .mdf file localized in VS repo works fine both in VS and MS SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot downgrade sql server databases or open a databse in older SQL server vesrions than it's original one at all and  It's different from `Compatibility level`.

when you install Visual studio it installs it's own sql server express edition instance witch can be different from instance that you installed with sql server stand alone installation.

you can try [SQL SERVER – How to Get List of SQL Server Instances Installed on a Machine?](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/11/12/sql-server-get-list-sql-server-instances-installed-machine/) to find out about your installed instances

Comment: it says I have only one instance 
LOCALMSSQLSERVER    REG_SZ    MSSQL15.LOCALMSSQLSERVER